# Search result based on URL

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query

Currently I am using bellow function to display search results from Custom Post Type.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'tgm_io_cpt_search' );
function tgm_io_cpt_search( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'lp_course', 'lp_lesson', 'products', 'portfolio' ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

I need something more advanced. I would like to set `post_type` based on referral parameter.

Lets say if customer is searching from `http://mywebsite/course`, then above function should change and return queries for curse only:

```
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'lp_course' ) );
```

I tried to do it via `HTTP_REFERER`, but was not successful.

```
$host =  $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

if ( $host == 'https://mywebsite/course' ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'lp_course') );
    }
} else {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'lp_course', 'lp_lesson', 'products', 'portfolio' ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Note that this would be incompatible with full page caching as the same URL would provide different results based on where the user had come from. btw did you know that you can just append the variables to the URL? e.g. `tomjn.com/talks/?s=right` searches my talks post type for the word right, as does `/?s=right&post_type=tomjn_talks`, using hidden inputs you can sneak plenty of extra parameters into a search form

Answer (score 0):

You don't and shouldn't rely on referrers ( they can be stripped, hidden, or just outright lies )

Instead there are alternatives

such as submitting to the post type archive:

```
<form action="/courses" method="get">
    <input type="test" name="s"/>
</form>
```

Or bundling query vars as hidden inputs:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="test" name="s"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="course" />
</form>
```

Or even just:

`mywebsite.com/?s=foo&post_type=course`

etc